# Screenshots and videos are created despite the settings

Tags: cypress

I faced with problem of self created screenshots and videos after failed test runs despite of settings in cypress.json file

```
"video": false,
"screenshotOnRunFailure": false
```

Also tried to configure via Screenshot.defaults with no luck

```
Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({
   screenshotOnRunFailure: false
 })
```

Cypress version is used: "9.2.1"

Cypress run command like this:

```
"cy:run": "npx cypress run --browser chrome"
```

How to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Could you give a little more context and details? How are the tests executed? What does the cypress run command look like?

Comment: Added in description:

    "cy:run": "npx cypress run --browser chrome"

Comment: When you open Cypress in headed mode, does the configuration reflect your changes? There is a settings tab on the Cypress window.

Comment: @jjhelguero yes, configuration reflects settings from cypress.json